# Unable to execute unit testcases [Karma and Webstorm 8]

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am unable to execute Karma unit testcases in WebStorm 8. Following is my Karam conf file -

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({

    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
        'vendor/angular/angular.js',
        'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/**/*spec.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [

    ],

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit', 'growl', 'coverage'
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera (has to be installed with `npm install karma-opera-launcher`)
    // - Safari (only Mac; has to be installed with `npm install karma-safari-launcher`)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows; has to be installed with `npm install karma-ie-launcher`)
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
    captureTimeout: 60000,


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
});
```

};

Following is the content of my spec file -

```
describe( 'Main section', function() {
beforeEach( module( 'util.main' ) );

it( 'should have a dummy test', inject( function() {
    expect( true ).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

});

But when I execute the test in WebStorm I get following error -

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module util.main due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'util.main' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/nomod?p0=util.main
    at E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:1677:17
    at ensure (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:1601:38)
    at module (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:1675:14)
    at E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:3878:22
    at forEach (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:3872:5)
    at Object.createInjector [as injector] (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:3812:11)
    at workFn (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2154:52)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/modulerr?p0=util.main&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'util.main'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.23%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dutil.main%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A78%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A1677%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A1601%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A1675%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A3878%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A325%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A3872%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.createInjector%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3F1410350966000%3A3812%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fvendor%2Fangular-mocks%2Fangular-mocks.js%3F1410350948000%3A2154%3A52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20jasmine.Block.execute%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9876%2Fbase%2Fnode_modules%2Fkarma-jasmine%2Flib%2Fjasmine.js%3F1410350172000%3A1145%3A17)
    at E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:3906:15
    at forEach (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:325:18)
    at loadModules (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:3872:5)
    at Object.createInjector [as injector] (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular/angular.js:3812:11)
    at workFn (E:/_work/Test/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2154:52)
```

Where am I going wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: could you try like this beforeEach( angular.mock.module( 'util.main',[] ) );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to let karma access your source files, so they can instantiate your util.main

```
files: [
        'vendor/angular/angular.js',
        'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'src/**/*spec.js'
        // add path to your source files here
    ],
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create addition file called Mocks.js and define your module mocks in that file for example

### Mock.js

```
angular.module('util.main,[]);
```

### and in  karma config

```
files: [
            // libraries
             'vendor/angular/angular.js',
             'vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',


            // our main app code
            'src/test/Mocks.js',
            'dist/js/app.js',

            // our test code
            'src/**/*spec.js'
        ],
```